# Bing maps multiple way points same location

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

I am having trouble with bing maps and multiple waypoints in the same location.

Ex: Go from A to B
Back to A to C
Back to B to A

The waypoints are on top of eachother and not assuming the letters from the route. A B C D E F.

How to deal?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected. The first pushpin added to the map is rendered on top. In this case "A", then "B".... So pushpins "E", "F"... are underneath A and B.